# What does it mean for a number to to be greater than another

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider this question, for what $x$, $$x>x+1$$
seems like doesn't have a solution. But consider $x=i-1$. Then, $x+1 = i$. And since the magnitude of $i-1$ is $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$ is $1$, it seems like $x=i-1$ is a solution. But it feels very wrong. And again, what if I start comparing two numbers like,

> Is $i$ greater or less than $1$?

Now, if I think that $i$ is as far from 0 as 1 is from 0, then $i$ must be equal to 1. That's thinking in terms of magnitude.  So, is $x=i-1$ a solution to $x>x+1$?

So, what does it mean for a number to be greater than another? Is it their magnitudes? Or it is their position, like, if a number lies to the right or above another number, then it is greater. Also, if a number lies to the right but below another, for instance, $2+3i$ lies above $3+2i$ but it also lies to the left. So which is greater? I don't know where I am going with this line of thinking but the more I think about it, the more it hurts my mind.

Comment: You must have run into this problem before you got to complex numbers. If $x=-2$ then the magnitude of $x$ is greater than the magnitude of $x+1.$ So what? It just shows that $|x|\gt|y|$ does not imply $x\gt y.$ In other words, the function $x\to|x|$ is not strictly increasing. You can tell that by looking at the graph of $y=|x|.$

Answer (score 0):

The standard order of the real numbers does not extend to the complex numbers. So $>$ in your question is not defined. (Of course you can define an order on $\mathbb{C}$, but you won't get a complete [archimedian ordered field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property))